# Is this the right way to position widgets, or is it a kludge?

Tags: android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

With two buttons in one horizontally-oriented LinearLayout, they look like this:

[image]

If I add a "Space" widget before the buttons, so that the LinearLayout xml is this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFetch"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button_Fetch" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button_Cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

...I'm satisfied with how it looks, with the buttons "right-aligned":

[image]

...but is this the "right" way to do it?

### UPDATE

At emulate-time, the "Cancel" button's text wrapped to two lines, so I added a "lines" property for it and adjusted the weight values (instead of 2, 1, 1 they are now 42, 29, 29) and it looks just right at emulate-time.

Comment: No, Space; it's in the XML above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't aware of the `Space` class, thank you for spotting that one out.

Anyway, no, I wouldn't do so.
I tend to avoid adding Views and Views, if I can achieve the same result with less.

I.e.: adding a

```
android:layout_margin="someValueInDP"
```

to the Buttons container.
**OR** (as alternative) you could add it:

```
android:padding="someValueInDP"
```

Keeping down the widget count helps for performances

**[EDIT]**

The difference between `layout_margin` and `padding`, as everyone knows (well, he/she is supposed to), is that the margin is a space OUTSIDE the View/Container, while the padding is a space INSIDE it.

Just to be clear about the subtle difference.

In other words: setting a margin will preserve the OUTER color as the "space" background, while a padding will ENLARGE the LinearLayout and ITS color will be seen (if different from the container it's in).